# Structuring a JSF 2 app for pure AJAX

Tags: java, ajax, jsf-2, facelets

I'm quite familiar with how to use AJAX in JSF 2. However, JSF 2 is designed with traditional page-to-page navigation in mind with AJAX thrown to allow the prevention of full reloads of the same page.

What I'm trying to figure out is a good way to build a pure AJAX web app with JSF 2. That is, a web app that only needs one initial full page load per user session.

Now, given enough time, I'm sure I could figure this out for myself, but I fear the solution may be awkward and I may paint myself into a corner.

One idea is to create composite components instead of pages then have one page that includes an instance of each composite component with the value of the `rendered` attribute calculated by comparing a unique page name with a session-scoped variable containing the current page name.

```xhtml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:page="http://java.sun.com/composite/components/pages">
<h:head>
    <title>MyApp | #{pageBean.title}</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <!-- Header, sidebars, etc. go here -->

    <!-- Pages -->
    <page:home id="home" rendered="#{pageBean.name == 'home'}"/>
    <page:search id="search" rendered="#{pageBean.name == 'search'}"/>
    <page:profile id="profile" rendered="#{pageBean.name = 'profile'}"/>
    <!-- etc... -->
</h:body>
```

This is only part of the picture, though. The page would have to be bookmarkable which would require hash-bangs and a javascript hash change handler. In fact, page navigation would probably take place by setting the anchor in javascript, allowing the hash change handler to take care of the rest.

Ideas?

Comment: I think you're going right through it. For bookmarkable pages, you can pass a parameter through the url and receive it either in a servlet or `@SessionScoped` managed bean. Parse it (it can go in plain text or hash coded) and display the page you want.

Comment: Why not go with existing technologies like PrimeFaces Mobile: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/mobile/index.jsf

Comment: Because 1. I didn't ask about writing a mobile web app and 2. PrimeFaces Mobile is a horrible piece of crap.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to do this using layout and templates that are dynamically loaded.
I have a single page layout and several of these are loaded content depending on the menu.
See how it looks:

```
<h:body>

        <p:layout fullPage="true">

            <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="80" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                <h:form id="form3">  
                    <ui:include src="./templates/template.xhtml" />  
                </h:form> 
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="100" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                Footer
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="west" header="Opciones" size="175">
                <h:form id="form1">
                    <p:panelMenu style="width:200px">   
                        <p:submenu label="Clientes" >
                            <p:menuitem value="Adicionar" update=":form2" actionListener="#{templateMB.templateAddCliente}" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Modificar" update=":form2" actionListener="#{templateMB.templateConfigCliente}" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Listado" update=":form2" actionListener="#{templateMB.templateListadoCliente}" />
                        </p:submenu> 
                        <p:submenu label="Contratos">  
                            <p:menuitem value="Adicionar" update=":form2" actionListener="#{templateMB.templateAddContrato}" />
                        </p:submenu>  
                        <p:separator/>  
                        <p:submenu label="Suplementos" >  
                            <p:menuitem value="Adicionar" icon="ui-icon-signal"/>  
                        </p:submenu>  
                    </p:panelMenu>
                </h:form>
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="center" id="centerlayout">
                <h:form id="form2">  
                    <ui:include src="#{templateMB.centerTemplate}" />  
                </h:form> 
                </p:layoutUnit>

        </p:layout>

    </h:body>
```

Backing bean:

```
    public String templateAddCliente() {
    try {
        this.centerTemplate = "./templates/addCliente.xhtml";
         return null;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage("Ha ocurrido un error: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}

  public String templateConfigCliente() {
    try {
        this.centerTemplate = "./templates/configCliente.xhtml";
         return null;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage("Ha ocurrido un error: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
  public String templateHome() {
    try {
        this.centerTemplate = "./templates/hometemplate.xhtml";
         return null;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage("Ha ocurrido un error: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}

  public String templateListadoCliente() {
    try {
        this.centerTemplate = "./templates/listadoCliente.xhtml";
         return null;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage("Ha ocurrido un error: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}

  public String templateAddContrato() {
    try {
        this.centerTemplate = "./templates/addContratos.xhtml";
         return null;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage("Ha ocurrido un error: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: is only an ideology of how to achieve it, but I need to figure out how to generate the load in the backing bean in a single method, identifying which menu item is invoked.¿?